# Load as you Scroll in XAML WinRT?

Tags: .net, user-interface, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Can someone give me a hint how to implement this in WinRT?

I want a functionality similar to bing image search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to look at building your custom collection to implement ISupportIncrementalLoading.  Take a look at [this blog post](http://michelsalib.com/2012/10/21/winrt-how-to-properly-implement-isupportincrementalloading-with-navigation/) to see an example.